# Asp.Net Core + GraphQL -> Schema does not appear

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

It's the first time I'm asking a question.
I want to build a graphQL server by using ASP.NET Core project.
I use [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/building-and-consuming-graphql-api-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)  line by line, but in the end, it does not show the schema. I tried every thing that i could. The intresting is that the server works. the only thing is that does not show the schema.

[image: graphql url]

here are some codes that I'm using.
Schema:

```
 public class RootSchema : Schema, ISchema
    {
        public RootSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
        {
            Query = resolver.Resolve<RootQuery>();
        }
    }
```

Query:

```
public class RootQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public RootQuery()
        {
            Field<AuthorType>(
                name: "authors", resolve: context =>
                {
                    return new Author()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Jane"
                    };
                });
        }
    }
```

The Controller:

```
[Route("graphql")]
    public class GraphQLController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ISchema _schema;
        private readonly IDocumentExecuter _executer;
        private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public GraphQLController(ISchema schema, IDocumentExecuter executer, IDependencyResolver resolver)
        {
            _schema = schema;
            _executer = executer;
            _resolver = resolver;
        }

        [HttpGet(nameof(Test))]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("Salam");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
        {
            var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(_ =>
            {
                _.Schema = _schema;
                _.Query = query.Query;
                _.Inputs = query.Variables?.ToInputs();
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
            {
                return Problem(detail: result.Errors.Select(_ => _.Message).FirstOrDefault(), statusCode: 500);
            }
            return Ok(result.Data);
        }
    }
```

The Configure function at the sturtup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseGraphiQl("/graphql");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseRouting(); 
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

The ConfigureServices function at the Sturtup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(_ => new
        FuncDependencyResolver(_.GetRequiredService));
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();

    services.AddScoped<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>();
    services.AddScoped<RootQuery>();
    services.AddScoped<AuthorType>();
    services.AddScoped<BlogPostType>();
    services.AddScoped<ISchema, RootSchema>();
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

any help would be appreciated.